# Distinct Column Values from Dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following data in my database:

### [image: Sample Data]

I am building a report where I have separate sections for County, State, and Country that display the distinct values for that column. For example, the Countries and States sections of the report would look something like:

```
Countries                       States
---------------------------     -------------------------
| Country Name | Primary? |     | State Name | Primary? |
---------------------------     -------------------------
| USA          |    Yes   |     | GA         |   Yes    |
---------------------------     | VA         |   No     |
                                -------------------------
```

I have been trying to accomplish this using tables, but am having trouble getting the data as distinct values. Is there a way to do this other than by creating a separate dataset for each type of data (State, Country, etc.)?

Comment: It is very possible to achieve your desired output, but what is the rule that defines a Country as Yes for Primary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used your data to get your expected results by adding two tablix to the report and groping on Country and State fields.

[image]

In the Primary? column I used this expression for Country table:

```
=IIF(
SUM(IIF(Fields!Primary.Value="True",1,0),"Country")>0
,"Yes","No"
)
```

For State table create a row group by `State` field and use this expression:

```
=IIF(
SUM(IIF(Fields!Primary.Value="True",1,0),"State")>0
,"Yes","No"
)
```

This is the preview of both tables.

[image]

> The Country and State tables must have the Country and State Row
>   Groups.

---

UPDATE:

In order to get the correct presentation avoiding multiple rows, you have to delete `Details` group as you can see in the screenshot there is only one group in Row Groups: `Country`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your response helped me realize that I needed to remove the "Details" group from my table. It is now working as you mentioned. Thanks for your help! Can you update your response to include that the "Details" group should be removed from the row groups section? Then I can mark it as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1496624, You are right I forgot explicitely say details group must be deleted. I've updated my answer.